# backgroundworker never instantiating in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

This code runs all the lines before the background worker but none of the background worker items:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Other code that runs

    // debugger never executes these lines of code????
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorkerRefreshData = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorkerRefreshData.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorkerRefreshData_DoWork);
    backgroundWorkerRefreshData.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Are there returns, possible exceptions, etc.?

Comment: step through in the debugger to see what's going on

Comment: FYI, I have a breakpoint on the backgroundworker variable instaintiation

Comment: Make sure your project is built. It happens sometimes that source and binaries are not in sync. Just re-build the solution.

Comment: I also build the project outside of running the debugger

Comment: want to talk about wierd, I moved some load code for a combo box and it works fine??? no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the backgroundworker code to the Form1() constructor  and see if it works there.

Otherwise it looks like a buggy execution.  I have had in the past where I add code to my project in visual studio 2010, and the execution never runs it.  I save my work shutdown Visual studio - relaunch it and the changes were not even saved.  If the first part doesn't work I recommend trying a visual studio reboot.